# Select from a not visible dropdown list in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, jquery, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to select a value from a dropdown list but I'm getting an `ElementNotVisibleException` error.

```
 new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(select.selectText[name=ADT]))).SelectByValue("2");
```

And you can see the website that I try to select from dropdown list is

[Css of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVP3f.jpg)

I believe there something to do with jQuery as well but I'm not sure..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with JavaScript. For example, if you have a hidden button, you can click that button in this way:

```
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginLink")));
```

See if you can apply the same thing for your dropdown element.
Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately not, i also tried
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(element)));

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just miss a quotation mark there?

css=selector.class[attribute='value']

In your case:

```
select.selectText[name='ADT']
```

or `""`

Comment: the problem is that i cannot select from dropdown, i can find the right place via cssSelector.

Comment: @E.Aksoy  Perhaps you should try selectByVisibleText NOT selectByValue

Comment: @E.Aksoy  selectByValue  you use when you have something like this
<option value="10"> England</option>

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
new Select(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(select.selectText[name='ADT']))).SelectByValue("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait until the element is visible using an explicit wait.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElement(By.cssSelector("select.selectText[name=ADT]")
```